# Does monitoring tools affect my website rank in google?

Tags: seo, google-search

It's been a month that I use a service that monitors my website and if the website is down email alerts are sent for me.

I checked my visitors last day and found that almost 5000 visits have been added two my site since using this service and this service is generating fake traffic for my web site.This service watches HTTP protocol and if HTTP service is down the email is sent.

My concern is that I don't know that this fake traffic affects my SEO or not! If yes I prefer not to use monitoring tools for my website.

Comment: How would Google Search be able to learn about this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO not programming

Comment: As you can see I have used SEO tag

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will have some trouble indirectly, because these visits can spoil your traffic quality. For example, if they increase bounce rate, that is a bad signal for Google. Besides that, you should create another view in Analytics, and apply filters to remove traffic from these sources in order to have a real insight into your traffic.

That tool should identify as a robot, so their visits are not counted in Analytics. If that's not the case, I would recommend changing the tool.